Tournament director overruling the main arbiter
Spawned from this question. In short, the tournament director shouldn't overrule the arbiter, but then, you shouldn't smoke either. Also, an arbiters decision might get overruled by a special tournament court, which happens now and then, so an arbiter isn't the last instance anyway. But may the tournament director overrule the arbiter? (Please give actual examples, if possible.)
